# Pandas: Convert String To Float Using Function

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm running a SQL query where the result has a column called 'type' that contains 'A' or 'B' as its value.  I want to convert 'A's to 0 and 'B's to 1.  As far as I can tell, dataframes don't allow strings so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Do I need to make this conversion using SQL first and then use Pandas to read the result into a dataframe?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean dataframes dont allow strings? please post an example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) value, you can do :

```
df['type'] = df['type'].replace("A",0).replace("B",1)
```

But Pandas DataFrame should allow the use of strings

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean by pandas not allowing strings, however a fast way to convert values to 0s and 1s would be the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'A'], columns=['x'])
df['x_int'] = (df['x'] == 'B').astype(int)
df

    x   x_int
0   A   0
1   B   1
2   A   0
```

Here you are first converting the series to booleans and then to integers

Answer (score 2):

Pandas DataFrames do allow strings, but most of prediction/regression/classification methods don't.

There are quite a few ways to convert strings to numeric values:

```
df['type'] = df['type'].map({'A':0, 'B':1})
```

IMO the most flexible ones are:

```
df['type'] = pd.factorize(df['type'])[0]
```

and

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df['type'] = le.fit_tramsform(df[['type']])
```